# Autoware.AI and Autoware.Auto on Same Machine

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I currently have ADE docker installed on my Linux machine that is running Autoware.Auto. I now want to use Autoware.AI on the same machine.

Is it okay to have both Autoware.Auto and Autoware.AI on the same Linux machine? If yes, do I need to install a separate docker container or I can install Autoware.AI inside the same docker that I used for Autoware.Auto?

Machine Specifications:

Linux Ubuntu 18.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/372597/autoware.ai-and-autoware.auto-on-same-machine/) by [shlokgoel](https://answers.ros.org/users/67161/shlokgoel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2021-02-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes you can have both in the same machine.

If you follow the instructions on Autoware.AI via docker (and docker instructions for Autoware.auto), then a seperate container is downloaded for you, so you do not have to take any extra steps.

Additionally, if you want both environments locally that is also possible. You then just source both environments individually, in individual terminals.

---

Originally posted by [turtleMaster20](https://answers.ros.org/users/70661/turtlemaster20/) with karma: 41 on 2021-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0